# How to use views hooks - specifically hook_view_data()?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I am looking for details on the api to define my own view data, such as what values I can provide for the table I am defining, what values are available for the fields etc.

I have found a tutorial that gives me the basic info, but now I need more specific info.

I have found this page

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7

but when I click on the link to

```
hook_views_data
```

I go to a page with virtually no information with one link which takes me back to the listing page I started at.

Is there somewhere I can find out information about what `hook_views_data` should define?

Comment: Views's documentation is incomplete, hard to read, sometimes outdated and buggy too. But we are not the ones who can help it. If you have a specific problem with specific thing you need to implement, ask us! Or ask Views team to fix their docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views does have complete documentation for that hook, but it's not in the most obvious place.

If you install the [Advanced Help](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module and go to http://mysite.com/help/views/api-tables you'll find the *Describing tables to Views* help page which contains extensive documentation and code samples.

You can also find the full Views' API docs at http://mysite.com/help/views/api with that module installed.

On top of that, the [list of functions that implement `hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/implementations/hook_views_data/7) would also be worth a look. The aggregator, book and node module implementations look to be well commented at first glance.

Comment: Thank you, I was begining to think it was just me.  Does anyone on the web make Advanced help available to the web in general via google, would be much more useful?

Comment: Advanced help content is just content supplied witha  module (i.e. in Views it's in the /help directory).  If you want to add to the docs, just open an issue and provide a patch to the HTML files.

Comment: @Clive I never expected to say this to you: Please use http://example.com and http://example.org in examples, not a commercial domain, especially not one that does not provide links you have used.